# How does one obtain the type of an uploaded file in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have tried:

```
self.data['uploaded_file'].content_type
```

However, this gives an error that says the object lacks a content_type attribute.

Any ideas as to why? Thank you.

What is the best way to verify file type in Django forms?

Answer (score 1):

The `content_type` attribute is only present on the `UploadedFile` instances contained in `request.FILES`; you will need to get the content type from that, or use `magic` to get it from the raw file data.

Comment: Thanks, then what is the best way to verify file type in Django forms?

Answer (score 0):

How could you tell a file is binary file or text or some other stuff?
Perhaps using the file extension is a way, but not always makes sense.

Comment: Right, I don't think that file extension checking is reliable.